# Does anyone know how to make Nuclear Throne or Enter The Gungeon camera movement in platformer in Godot?

Tags: gdscript

When I writing my own script for this movement camera just flies away

I tried many variants but they dont work

Here`s script:

```
extends Camera2D

const smooth_lean := 10.0
const scale_lean := 0.2

func lean_camera_towards_mouse_(delta:float) -> void:
    var mouse_position := get_global_mouse_position()
    
    var direction_to_mouse := (mouse_position - position).normalized()
    var distance_to_mouse := mouse_position.distance_to(position)
    var lean := direction_to_mouse * distance_to_mouse * scale_lean
    
    offset = lerp(offset, lean, delta * smooth_lean)


func match_player_position_() -> void:
    position = get_node("/root/TEST Scene/Player/Player Collision").position


func _process(delta) -> void:
    lean_camera_towards_mouse_(delta)
    match_player_position_()
```

there is videos:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SzOXAzO_TA&ab_channel=Wanderbots
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3IvM0f2Lvw&ab_channel=Throneful

Comment: Hi, it would be a good idea to post the code that you tried, even if it doesn't work , particularly the code that causes the camera to just fly away, we can have a look at it and find out why. Also if you can, please link to videos of the games that have the camera movement you are wanting to emulate so we can have a look at what you are trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: just made this .

Answer (score 1):

From watching the videos, it appears that all you want to do is set the camera position somewhere between the player position and the mouse position. To allow this you need to make the player accessible to the camera; you may use an export NodePath to the camera2D object and set this in the editor.

```
extends Camera2D

export (NodePath) var Player = null

# Scale of the 'lean', maximum value should be 0.5 to make sense, minimum is 0
export (float) var Scale = 0.2

func _process(delta) -> void:
    var player_node = get_node(Player)
    var player_position = player_node.global_position
    var mouse_position = get_global_mouse_position()
    # get position between player and mouse position
    var camera_position = player_position + (mouse_position-player_position)*Scale;
    global_position = camera_position
```

If using [Godot 4+](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_exports.html) change export syntax to the following:

```
@export var Player : NodePath = "";

# Scale of the 'lean', maximum value should be 0.5 to make sense, minimum is 0
@export var Scale : float = 0.2
```

After adding and saving the export to the script you can now open the inspector window and assign the Player NodePath of the Camera2D object to your player node.

[image: Assign player to your player node (1)]

[image: Assign player to your player node (2)]

You can also edit 'Scale' within the inspector window if you want to increase/reduce the scale of the camera extent to the mouse per scene. Increase 'Scale' to make the camera "lean" further from the player.

You may not require built-in Camera2D smoothing as the mouse naturally provides the smooth movement.

You may need to add extra limits to the camera in future to prevent the camera from viewing outside of the map.

Comment: In the export (NodePath) and export (float) lines error: Unexpected "Identifier" in class body.

Comment: What version of Godot are you using?

Comment: I've added changed syntax if you are using Godot 4

Comment: Yes im using Godot 4

Comment: Everything is working when I assigning it to the collision of player, but when I assigning it to the player camera just goes to the centre of the screen

Comment: The "Player" export should be assigned to the player within the scene. I'm not sure what you mean by assigning "it" to the player camera. What is "it" and what is the "player camera". Is your Camera2D a child of the player? Can you show a snapshot of the node hierarchy in your scene to better understand what you are assigning things to ? I think this might be the source of your problems. You can update your question to do so. Thanks